# How to separate Spans in table using styled components - React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I've got this really annoying CSS issue. So im rendering these tags as spans like in the picture below but I cant get them to seperate top and bottom, theyre stuck togetehr and I dont know  why.
Im using styled components to .map them out and render them as individual spans

[image]

```js
<TableBody >
          {props.filteredData(props.API_DATA,props.filters).map((row,index) => (
           <>
           <TableRow  key={row.name}>
            <TableCell style={{ textAlign:"left", width:'5%'}} align="center">{index + 1}</TableCell> 
              <TableCell style={{ textAlign:"left", width:'25%'}}   align="center">{row.bnd}</TableCell> 
              <TableCell style={{ textAlign:"left", width:'5%'}}  align="center">{row.cnt}</TableCell>
              <TableCell style={{ textAlign:"left", width:'20%'}}  align="center">{row.prt.map((e) => <span  key={e}><span style={{backgroundColor:"#FFD9B6", padding:"1px",display:"flex",width:"80px", border:"0.5px solid orange", borderRadius:"3px"}}>{e}</span></span>)}</TableCell>
              <TableCell style={{ textAlign:"left", width:'25%'}}  align="center"><a href={row.url}>{row.url}</a></TableCell>
            </TableRow>
            <Waypoint onEnter={()=>limitHandler(index + 10)}/>
          </>
          ))}
          
        </TableBody>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add a `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` to the `<span>` tag.

Try this:

```
<span key={e} style={{...styleProperties, margin: "10px 0px"}}>{e}</span>
```

I advice you to avoid styling component in that way, try to use a .css module outside or .scss

Read this [article](https://www.sitepoint.com/react-components-styling-options/)

Comment: huh I thought I tried that already, well it works now thanks bro

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem well, you just have to add margins. Is that correct?

```js
<TableBody >
          {props.filteredData(props.API_DATA,props.filters).map((row,index) => (
           <>
           <TableRow  key={row.name}>
            <TableCell style={{ textAlign:"left", width:'5%'}} align="center">{index + 1}</TableCell> 
              <TableCell style={{ textAlign:"left", width:'25%'}}   align="center">{row.bnd}</TableCell> 
              <TableCell style={{ textAlign:"left", width:'5%'}}  align="center">{row.cnt}</TableCell>
              <TableCell style={{ textAlign:"left", width:'20%'}}  align="center">{row.prt.map((e) => <span  key={e}><span style={{backgroundColor:"#FFD9B6", padding:"1px",display:"flex",width:"80px", border:"0.5px solid orange", borderRadius:"3px"; margin: "5px"}}>{e}</span></span>)}</TableCell>
              <TableCell style={{ textAlign:"left", width:'25%'}}  align="center"><a href={row.url}>{row.url}</a></TableCell>
            </TableRow>
            <Waypoint onEnter={()=>limitHandler(index + 10)}/>
          </>
          ))}
          
        </TableBody>
```

Tested on codepen inside of a table.
[Check out there - imgur.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73FAo.png)